# Query on multiple table to update value

Tags: mysql

I have a bad table structure  with two table cost and invoice

in my table cost I added a new column inv

I want to update all lines in table cost with the value in table invoice if exist in table inv
I tried this query

```
UPDATE cost 
SET cost.inv = (
SELECT inv.IDT 
    FROM inv,cost
    WHERE inv.file = cost.IDT
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use multiple-table syntax for UPDATE statement, not a subquery.

```sql
UPDATE cost
JOIN inv ON inv.file = cost.IDT
SET cost.inv = inv.IDT
```

If there is more then one row in `inv` which matches the row in `cost` then indefinite row value will be used for updating.

Answer (score 0):

I use this syntax for update a column with other joined table. Inner join guarantees that inv is not null and exists. If you want to get more filtered results you can use where or additional join clauses.

```
UPDATE cost SET cost.inv = inv.IDT
FROM cost 
JOIN inv ON inv.file = cost.IDT
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/9193372) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.